# How do I retrieve my backed up wallet to Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, backup

I backed up my Bitcoin wallet on a drive for safety. Luck has it that my computer crashed. So now I downloaded Bitcoin Core, but do not how to retrieve my backup. Please help. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Restoring a wallet on a fresh machine:

1. Start Bitcoin-Core (daemon or Qt), shut it down after it has started up (you only do that to create the necessary data directory)
2. Replace `wallet.dat` with your backed-up `wallet.dat` (see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory if you can't find the data dir)
3. Startup Bitcoin-Core, wait until your node is in sync (can take a couple of hours/days)

**If you have created the wallet with Bitcoin-Core >= 0.14 (HD Wallet).**

2a. Startup Bitcoin-Core (Qt/core), call `getnewaddress` 100-10000 times (depending on how many addresses you have created)
(This hopefully will go away in Core 0.15)

Comment: What does it mean: "call getnewaddress 100-10000 times"? How to do it on windows?

Comment: Call it via bitcoin-cli 10000 times (maybe write a script).

Comment: Did `-rescan` option not work for 0.14? It does the job in 0.15.