# How to sync my backed up wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, backup

I backed up my wallet from computer A. restored the backup on computer B. then I spent some amount of bitcoin from computer A.

Now my restored wallet on computer B shows the old balance which is obviously wrong. how do I sync wallet on computer B to find how much of it is actually spent?

Comment: We'll need to know which wallet software you're using in order to help.

Comment: bitcoin-core qt

Comment: Similar question here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52612/how-do-i-retrieve-my-backed-up-wallet-to-bitcoin-core