# Where to download "Bitcoin core" wallet application from?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Why there are 2-3 bitcoin core applications online?

- bitcoin-qt at bitcoin.org,
- bitcoin knots
- bitcoin core on bitcoincore.org

Which should I use?

Comment: Please split up your questions into topics (one question per topic). The variety of Bitcoin client downloads seems unrelated to the rest. About the rest: you'll need to give a lot more information. Which transactions? Why do you expect them to show up? Are they yours? How did you import or create them? Where are they coming from?

Comment: that was a very long time ago so, so given the weather, I'll be as specific as I can!
Comes from mining, bought more than 10 years ago.
it's all bitcoin-qt coins, in wallet.dat s!
I can open them on bitcoin-qt, but nothing, no trace, for me, who knows how to read, little or not, the outputs of the DEBUG file

Comment: buying, coins gathered, on a bitcoin-qt client, no passphrase (bitcoin-qt)

Comment: But, two months ago, I have out of the client -qt, priv key on electrum, But the file WAS in .txt file ... That It's sure

Comment: and haveing more file wallet.dat, more than this alone

Comment: Of course you will be paid

Comment: This site is not a job ad.

Comment: CAN help me ??please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve my backed up wallet to Bitcoin Core?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52612/how-do-i-retrieve-my-backed-up-wallet-to-bitcoin-core)

Comment: loadwallet and -rescan = replace new wallet.dat out of wallet folder and replace the old save wallet.dat in wallet folder and -rescan ?? it's = they 2 commands ?

Comment: do not can, other option please !

Comment: one wallet.dat of 2012-1014, I have an completely downloading blockchain, What I do ? no prejudiciable, option know also exprimed, juste help me ! what I talk !

Comment: I have wallet.dat from 2011 to 2014 (save bitcoin core) with private keys in it, a blockchain uploaded to bitcoin-qt client.
how to recover keys WITH COINS and TRANSACTIONS? please

Comment: I have edited this question to focus on the first of the many questions in the original text. I believe the other questions will be answered by answers to one of your several other questions. If you dislike what I have done you can use "rollback" in the "edited2 link above.

Answer (score 1):

### Websites

As of June 2022 the website I would advise you to use to obtain Bitcoin Core is bitcoincore.org.

Bitcoin knots is a completely different program.

The bitcoincore.org website is operated by the maintainers of the Bitcoin Core repository and is the project's own site, while bitcoin.org is operated by independent people. Historically, the Bitcoin Core software was published on bitcoin.org, but as ownership grew apart, this transitioned into it just being mirrored there. At at June 2022 the maintainers of the bitcoin.org website have not mirrored on their website the latest software from bitcoincore.org.

Therefore I would not download Bitcoin core from bitcoin.org.

The bitcoin.org website is a good source of information about Bitcoin and about a variety of different Bitcoin wallet applications. I believe that is its main purpose.

---

### Application names

There can be confusion over similar names for Bitcoin software

The original Bitcoin application created by Satoshi Nakamoto was named simply "Bitcoin".

As multiple Bitcoin wallets were developed by many different independent developers, It was decided to rename "Bitcoin" to "Bitcoin Core". This gave it a separate name that would be less likely to be confused with other independent applications. "Bitcoin Core" is not the same thing as "Bitcoin Knots"

If you download and install the Bitcoin Core application you will probably find you have several distinct executable programs.

- bitcoin-qt.exe - a wallet application with a simple graphical user interface. This is the main application and is all that would normally be used by anyone who just wants a uncomplicated Bitcoin wallet for ordinary simple Bitcoin transactions. This is why some people refer to "bitcoin-qt" instead of saying "Bitcoin Core". The history is a little more complicated but this is all we really need to know.

In a "daemon" subdirectory might be

- bitcoin-cli.exe
- bitcoind.exe
- bitcoin-tx.exe
- bitcoin-wallet.exe

These are a group of programs that communicate with each other. They are intended for more advanced users and for more advanced purposes. They should not be used at the same time as bitcoin-qt.exe.

You can find out more using the help built into these programs. Open a command prompt, use `cd <directory path>` to navigate to the installation folder and type `bitcoin-wallet -?`

---

<sub>I have made this answer community wiki to acknowledge and make clear that it is the result of community effort. Any errors are mine alone as at 2022-06-09</sub>

Comment: This is mostly right, but perhaps missing this: bitcoincore.org is operated by the maintainers of the Bitcoin Core repository and is the project's own site, while bitcoin.org is operated by independent people. Historically, the Bitcoin Core software was published on bitcoin.org, but as ownership grew apart, this transitioned into it just being mirrorred there. Now it appears that it's not even up to date anymore.

Comment: @Pieter: Thanks, I have edited my answer and replaced my paragraph with yours.

Comment: bitcoin core, created and coded by satoshi nakamoto? that's what it says! why is it not true?

Comment: Hi signbertrand, we are only a Q&A site. We do not allow job postings, and everyone here is a volunteer. Please tune back your expectations. Perhaps you could try the French Bitcoin Talk forum: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=13.0